# How to view or output a very long string from a console

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, object, console

I am messing around with firefox console and I want to view the content of an object.

I first called `JSON.stringify(object)` on the object but got the `TypeError: cyclic object value` error.

I found the solution was to exclude already serialized ojectcts with this code

```
seen = []

JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, val) {
   if (val != null && typeof val == "object") {
        if (seen.indexOf(val) >= 0)
            return
        seen.push(val)
    }
    return val
})
```

When i called JSON.stringify on the above code snippet i get part of the object that I am looking for yet at the bottom i get a msg:

*The string you are trying to view is too long to be displayed by the Web Console.*

I would like to output this string into a file or view it somehow.

I tried creating a function and then calling console.log on that function:

```
console.log(myFunction);
```

Which returned

console.log(myFunction());
undefined
undefined

I dont know if this is an actual solution. If so how can i access the console log to see my object

Comment: `ReferenceError: tringify is not defined` <-- Looks like you made a typo. `tringify` should be `stringify`.

Comment: I didn't mean you made a typo in the question, but in your actual code. What line is causing that error?

Comment: So, that's the solution? :P

Comment: Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add results somewhere into current page ex. like this and copy/paste out then if you want:

```js
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(biggerInlinedJson(), null, 2);
console.log(jsonStr);
/*
document.body.innerText = jsonStr;
/*/
var el = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
el.innerText = jsonStr;
document.body.appendChild(el);
el = document.createElement("PRE");
el.innerText = jsonStr;
document.body.appendChild(el);
//*/
function biggerInlinedJson() {
// small part of https://github.com/zemirco/sf-city-lots-json/blob/master/citylots.json
  return {"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0001001","BLKLOT": "0001001","BLOCK_NUM": "0001","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "0","TO_ST": "0","STREET": "UNKNOWN","ST_TYPE": null,"ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.422003528252475,37.808480096967251,0.0],[-122.422076013325281,37.808835019815085,0.0],[-122.421102174348633,37.808803534992904,0.0],[-122.421062569067274,37.808601056818148,0.0],[-122.422003528252475,37.808480096967251,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0002001","BLKLOT": "0002001","BLOCK_NUM": "0002","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "0","TO_ST": "0","STREET": "UNKNOWN","ST_TYPE": null,"ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.42082593937107,37.808631474146033,0.0],[-122.420858049679694,37.808795641369592,0.0],[-122.419811958704301,37.808761809714007,0.0],[-122.42082593937107,37.808631474146033,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0004002","BLKLOT": "0004002","BLOCK_NUM": "0004","LOT_NUM": "002","FROM_ST": "0","TO_ST": "0","STREET": "UNKNOWN","ST_TYPE": null,"ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.415701204606876,37.808327252671461,0.0],[-122.415760743593196,37.808630700240904,0.0],[-122.413787891332404,37.808566801319841,0.0],[-122.415701204606876,37.808327252671461,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0005001","BLKLOT": "0005001","BLOCK_NUM": "0005","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "206","TO_ST": "286","STREET": "JEFFERSON","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.417346670944355,37.808121127609709,0.0],[-122.417457443198046,37.808685627252729,0.0],[-122.416003128921787,37.808638547938997,0.0],[-122.41593547450509,37.808293744156337,0.0],[-122.417346670944355,37.808121127609709,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0006001","BLKLOT": "0006001","BLOCK_NUM": "0006","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "350","TO_ST": "366","STREET": "JEFFERSON","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.418974650424474,37.807907564012595,0.0],[-122.419147512636712,37.808655940108665,0.0],[-122.418623049836171,37.808723347475208,0.0],[-122.417699830020709,37.808693471445764,0.0],[-122.417580761531511,37.808086708494429,0.0],[-122.418974650424474,37.807907564012595,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0007001","BLKLOT": "0007001","BLOCK_NUM": "0007","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "2936","TO_ST": "2936","STREET": "HYDE","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.420642521491033,37.807693733698322,0.0],[-122.420789444036856,37.808444893986632,0.0],[-122.419379916821399,37.808626069865937,0.0],[-122.419207175169234,37.807878227427288,0.0],[-122.420642521491033,37.807693733698322,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0010001","BLKLOT": "0010001","BLOCK_NUM": "0010","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "600","TO_ST": "600","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.419831772538799,37.807205123871363,0.0],[-122.419834114387342,37.807218024451856,0.0],[-122.419911601942303,37.807596413960987,0.0],[-122.419195209587571,37.807688494444044,0.0],[-122.419042562933925,37.806943049955677,0.0],[-122.419651559416494,37.806867022433515,0.0],[-122.41966578303186,37.806882315196049,0.0],[-122.419675249958857,37.806892965734285,0.0],[-122.419684481692087,37.806903745368572,0.0],[-122.41969347477874,37.806914652352724,0.0],[-122.419702226784878,37.806925680417926,0.0],[-122.41971073428104,37.806936828718861,0.0],[-122.419718996038398,37.806948093670719,0.0],[-122.419727007398933,37.806959470843303,0.0],[-122.419734768292656,37.806970957534197,0.0],[-122.419742275196839,37.806982549294638,0.0],[-122.419749525770555,37.806994243459279,0.0],[-122.419756518785348,37.807006036443219,0.0],[-122.419763250741596,37.80701792469862,0.0],[-122.41976972038735,37.807029903739888,0.0],[-122.419775925381813,37.807041970901494,0.0],[-122.41978186333769,37.807054121716284,0.0],[-122.419787534184863,37.807066353481837,0.0],[-122.419792934400533,37.807078661749401,0.0],[-122.419798062756087,37.80709104293426,0.0],[-122.419802919134909,37.8071034925322,0.0],[-122.419807500084048,37.807116008797045,0.0],[-122.419811805440261,37.807128585423044,0.0],[-122.4198158339982,37.807141219726184,0.0],[-122.419819582281661,37.807153909059409,0.0],[-122.419823052421464,37.80716664798085,0.0],[-122.419826240918098,37.807179432942604,0.0],[-122.419829147655008,37.807192259440548,0.0],[-122.419831772538799,37.807205123871363,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0010002","BLKLOT": "0010002","BLOCK_NUM": "0010","LOT_NUM": "002","FROM_ST": "680","TO_ST": "680","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.419911601942303,37.807596413960987,0.0],[-122.419834114387342,37.807218024451856,0.0],[-122.419831772538799,37.807205123871363,0.0],[-122.419829147655008,37.807192259440548,0.0],[-122.419826240918098,37.807179432942604,0.0],[-122.419823052421464,37.80716664798085,0.0],[-122.419819582281661,37.807153909059409,0.0],[-122.4198158339982,37.807141219726184,0.0],[-122.419811805440261,37.807128585423044,0.0],[-122.419807500084048,37.807116008797045,0.0],[-122.419802919134909,37.8071034925322,0.0],[-122.419798062756087,37.80709104293426,0.0],[-122.419792934400533,37.807078661749401,0.0],[-122.419787534184863,37.807066353481837,0.0],[-122.41978186333769,37.807054121716284,0.0],[-122.419775925381813,37.807041970901494,0.0],[-122.41976972038735,37.807029903739888,0.0],[-122.419763250741596,37.80701792469862,0.0],[-122.419756518785348,37.807006036443219,0.0],[-122.419749525770555,37.806994243459279,0.0],[-122.419742275196839,37.806982549294638,0.0],[-122.419734768292656,37.806970957534197,0.0],[-122.419727007398933,37.806959470843303,0.0],[-122.419718996038398,37.806948093670719,0.0],[-122.41971073428104,37.806936828718861,0.0],[-122.419702226784878,37.806925680417926,0.0],[-122.41969347477874,37.806914652352724,0.0],[-122.419684481692087,37.806903745368572,0.0],[-122.419675249958857,37.806892965734285,0.0],[-122.41966578303186,37.806882315196049,0.0],[-122.419651559416494,37.806867022433515,0.0],[-122.420461058485998,37.806765958191221,0.0],[-122.420606028190718,37.807507152530022,0.0],[-122.419911601942303,37.807596413960987,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0011007","BLKLOT": "0011007","BLOCK_NUM": "0011","LOT_NUM": "007","FROM_ST": "580","TO_ST": "580","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.418809684489474,37.806970324642684,0.0],[-122.418962748829145,37.807717822765618,0.0],[-122.418261722815416,37.807807921694092,0.0],[-122.418114728237924,37.807058866808987,0.0],[-122.418809684489474,37.806970324642684,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0011008","BLKLOT": "0011008","BLOCK_NUM": "0011","LOT_NUM": "008","FROM_ST": "500","TO_ST": "550","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.418114728237924,37.807058866808987,0.0],[-122.418261722815416,37.807807921694092,0.0],[-122.417544151208375,37.807900142836701,0.0],[-122.417397010603693,37.807150305505004,0.0],[-122.418114728237924,37.807058866808987,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0012001","BLKLOT": "0012001","BLOCK_NUM": "0012","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "211","TO_ST": "229","STREET": "JEFFERSON","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.416294033786585,37.807666226310545,0.0],[-122.416294886455816,37.807670568010444,0.0],[-122.416369267444708,37.808049644457611,0.0],[-122.415904752976346,37.808106461463737,0.0],[-122.415828688765814,37.807728225901798,0.0],[-122.415985427567151,37.807708841455621,0.0],[-122.416155584810824,37.807683349374365,0.0],[-122.416294033786585,37.807666226310545,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0012002","BLKLOT": "0012002","BLOCK_NUM": "0012","LOT_NUM": "002","FROM_ST": "2701","TO_ST": "2739","STREET": "TAYLOR","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.415911277106133,37.807340016819225,0.0],[-122.415985427567151,37.807708841455621,0.0],[-122.415828688765814,37.807728225901798,0.0],[-122.415754622732734,37.807359914400728,0.0],[-122.415911277106133,37.807340016819225,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0012003","BLKLOT": "0012003","BLOCK_NUM": "0012","LOT_NUM": "003","FROM_ST": "418","TO_ST": "420","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.416082173010636,37.807318310533695,0.0],[-122.416155584810824,37.807683349374365,0.0],[-122.415985427567151,37.807708841455621,0.0],[-122.415911277106133,37.807340016819225,0.0],[-122.416082173010636,37.807318310533695,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0012003A","BLKLOT": "0012003A","BLOCK_NUM": "0012","LOT_NUM": "003A","FROM_ST": "430","TO_ST": "498","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.417162216503215,37.807181122787213,0.0],[-122.417235430903347,37.807554239113351,0.0],[-122.416961818452833,37.807588080624718,0.0],[-122.416722407235298,37.807617692329522,0.0],[-122.416551398764838,37.807638842611411,0.0],[-122.416294033786585,37.807666226310545,0.0],[-122.416155584810824,37.807683349374365,0.0],[-122.416082173010636,37.807318310533695,0.0],[-122.417162216503215,37.807181122787213,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0012005","BLKLOT": "0012005","BLOCK_NUM": "0012","LOT_NUM": "005","FROM_ST": "211","TO_ST": "295","STREET": "JEFFERSON","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.417235430903347,37.807554239113351,0.0],[-122.417310061285463,37.807934565483848,0.0],[-122.417036376757082,37.807968044225866,0.0],[-122.416961818452833,37.807588080624718,0.0],[-122.417235430903347,37.807554239113351,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0012006","BLKLOT": "0012006","BLOCK_NUM": "0012","LOT_NUM": "006","FROM_ST": "273","TO_ST": "275","STREET": "JEFFERSON","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.416961818452833,37.807588080624718,0.0],[-122.417036376757082,37.807968044225866,0.0],[-122.416796901587219,37.807997337169787,0.0],[-122.416722407235298,37.807617692329522,0.0],[-122.416961818452833,37.807588080624718,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0012007","BLKLOT": "0012007","BLOCK_NUM": "0012","LOT_NUM": "007","FROM_ST": "245","TO_ST": "281","STREET": "JEFFERSON","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.416722407235298,37.807617692329522,0.0],[-122.416796901587219,37.807997337169787,0.0],[-122.416625847775421,37.808018260274721,0.0],[-122.416551398764838,37.807638842611411,0.0],[-122.416722407235298,37.807617692329522,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0012007A","BLKLOT": "0012007A","BLOCK_NUM": "0012","LOT_NUM": "007A","FROM_ST": "235","TO_ST": "245","STREET": "JEFFERSON","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.416551398764838,37.807638842611411,0.0],[-122.416625847775421,37.808018260274721,0.0],[-122.416369267444708,37.808049644457611,0.0],[-122.416294886455816,37.807670568010444,0.0],[-122.416294033786585,37.807666226310545,0.0],[-122.416551398764838,37.807638842611411,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0013001","BLKLOT": "0013001","BLOCK_NUM": "0013","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "101","TO_ST": "101","STREET": "JEFFERSON","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.414338439683434,37.80805250792249,0.0],[-122.414387180618718,37.808294900407844,0.0],[-122.41426228957981,37.808310535848904,0.0],[-122.414212768110545,37.808068253318332,0.0],[-122.414338439683434,37.80805250792249,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0013004","BLKLOT": "0013004","BLOCK_NUM": "0013","LOT_NUM": "004","FROM_ST": "350","TO_ST": "350","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.414619000362336,37.807704566138106,0.0],[-122.414578099218801,37.807501164411832,0.0],[-122.415048225027292,37.807442260774678,0.0],[-122.415123212578521,37.807815164685138,0.0],[-122.414952256767194,37.807836583943718,0.0],[-122.414653084468426,37.807874068617039,0.0],[-122.414619000362336,37.807704566138106,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0013005","BLKLOT": "0013005","BLOCK_NUM": "0013","LOT_NUM": "005","FROM_ST": "380","TO_ST": "380","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.415123212578521,37.807815164685138,0.0],[-122.415048225027292,37.807442260774678,0.0],[-122.415518351225245,37.807383355244703,0.0],[-122.415593341078051,37.807756258860344,0.0],[-122.415251429922563,37.807799099393691,0.0],[-122.415123212578521,37.807815164685138,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0013006","BLKLOT": "0013006","BLOCK_NUM": "0013","LOT_NUM": "006","FROM_ST": "175","TO_ST": "175","STREET": "JEFFERSON","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.415327457607248,37.808177175453899,0.0],[-122.415251429922563,37.807799099393691,0.0],[-122.415593341078051,37.807756258860344,0.0],[-122.415669376880885,37.808134363437667,0.0],[-122.415327457607248,37.808177175453899,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0013006A","BLKLOT": "0013006A","BLOCK_NUM": "0013","LOT_NUM": "006A","FROM_ST": "165","TO_ST": "165","STREET": "JEFFERSON","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.415251429922563,37.807799099393691,0.0],[-122.415327457607248,37.808177175453899,0.0],[-122.415199239324664,37.808193229116014,0.0],[-122.415123212578521,37.807815164685138,0.0],[-122.415251429922563,37.807799099393691,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0013007","BLKLOT": "0013007","BLOCK_NUM": "0013","LOT_NUM": "007","FROM_ST": "155","TO_ST": "155","STREET": "JEFFERSON","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.415123212578521,37.807815164685138,0.0],[-122.415199239324664,37.808193229116014,0.0],[-122.415028278886751,37.808214634125207,0.0],[-122.414952256767194,37.807836583943718,0.0],[-122.415123212578521,37.807815164685138,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0013009","BLKLOT": "0013009","BLOCK_NUM": "0013","LOT_NUM": "009","FROM_ST": "2601","TO_ST": "2621","STREET": "MASON","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.414407145131847,37.807522583764019,0.0],[-122.414448044683482,37.807725985567188,0.0],[-122.414619000362336,37.807704566138106,0.0],[-122.414653084468426,37.807874068617039,0.0],[-122.414185063838332,37.807932706648621,0.0],[-122.414108875056641,37.80755995329698,0.0],[-122.414407145131847,37.807522583764019,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0013010","BLKLOT": "0013010","BLOCK_NUM": "0013","LOT_NUM": "010","FROM_ST": "330","TO_ST": "330","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.414578099218801,37.807501164411832,0.0],[-122.414619000362336,37.807704566138106,0.0],[-122.414448044683482,37.807725985567188,0.0],[-122.414407145131847,37.807522583764019,0.0],[-122.414578099218801,37.807501164411832,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0013016","BLKLOT": "0013016","BLOCK_NUM": "0013","LOT_NUM": "016","FROM_ST": "145","TO_ST": "145","STREET": "JEFFERSON","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.414952256767194,37.807836583943718,0.0],[-122.415028278886751,37.808214634125207,0.0],[-122.414387180618718,37.808294900407844,0.0],[-122.414338439683434,37.80805250792249,0.0],[-122.414212768110545,37.808068253318332,0.0],[-122.414185063838332,37.807932706648621,0.0],[-122.414653084468426,37.807874068617039,0.0],[-122.414952256767194,37.807836583943718,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0014001","BLKLOT": "0014001","BLOCK_NUM": "0014","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "200","TO_ST": "250","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.41387534685299,37.807591944759849,0.0],[-122.414028014513846,37.808338893395749,0.0],[-122.412628823675121,37.808514056480739,0.0],[-122.412467234107098,37.807771752503548,0.0],[-122.41387534685299,37.807591944759849,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0015001","BLKLOT": "0015001","BLOCK_NUM": "0015","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "100","TO_ST": "100","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.412232100480267,37.807797604245366,0.0],[-122.412380292819222,37.808478380209429,0.0],[-122.41088274965449,37.808255407080274,0.0],[-122.410821872975475,37.807975723213382,0.0],[-122.412232100480267,37.807797604245366,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0016001","BLKLOT": "0016001","BLOCK_NUM": "0016","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "50","TO_ST": "50","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.410592413481098,37.807998763487419,0.0],[-122.410640850333579,37.808221300480909,0.0],[-122.40983206407094,37.808096148276142,0.0],[-122.410592413481098,37.807998763487419,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0017002","BLKLOT": "0017002","BLOCK_NUM": "0017","LOT_NUM": "002","FROM_ST": "2","TO_ST": "2","STREET": "NORTH POINT","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.40884064163788,37.807265788581859,0.0],[-122.408971265666096,37.807922351525569,0.0],[-122.407742407701576,37.807404149389193,0.0],[-122.40884064163788,37.807265788581859,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0018001","BLKLOT": "0018001","BLOCK_NUM": "0018","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "1","TO_ST": "1","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.410005479597814,37.807501819935936,0.0],[-122.410079376248959,37.807873219458557,0.0],[-122.409139628142015,37.807993576852425,0.0],[-122.409065356533446,37.807620271426813,0.0],[-122.410005479597814,37.807501819935936,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0018004","BLKLOT": "0018004","BLOCK_NUM": "0018","LOT_NUM": "004","FROM_ST": "2300","TO_ST": "2340","STREET": "STOCKTON","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.410079376248959,37.807873219458557,0.0],[-122.410005479597814,37.807501819935936,0.0],[-122.409931265348433,37.807128819539976,0.0],[-122.410401324612195,37.807069592157774,0.0],[-122.410549249716013,37.807813037493446,0.0],[-122.410079376248959,37.807873219458557,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0018005","BLKLOT": "0018005","BLOCK_NUM": "0018","LOT_NUM": "005","FROM_ST": "100","TO_ST": "100","STREET": "NORTH POINT","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.409931265348433,37.807128819539976,0.0],[-122.410005479597814,37.807501819935936,0.0],[-122.409065356533446,37.807620271426813,0.0],[-122.408991146911589,37.80724727134843,0.0],[-122.409931265348433,37.807128819539976,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0019001","BLKLOT": "0019001","BLOCK_NUM": "0019","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "151","TO_ST": "151","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.412043168952366,37.806865166693555,0.0],[-122.412192443439778,37.807611425391009,0.0],[-122.410778581599033,37.807790003867005,0.0],[-122.410630003242773,37.807043287154272,0.0],[-122.412043168952366,37.806865166693555,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0020001","BLKLOT": "0020001","BLOCK_NUM": "0020","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "211","TO_ST": "211","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.413689126713351,37.806663024364099,0.0],[-122.413841139490842,37.807405073238677,0.0],[-122.412427492795132,37.807585587701496,0.0],[-122.412277895153991,37.806837721333068,0.0],[-122.413689126713351,37.806663024364099,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0021001","BLKLOT": "0021001","BLOCK_NUM": "0021","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "400","TO_ST": "400","STREET": "NORTH POINT","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.415331176192808,37.806450649477362,0.0],[-122.415479174354985,37.807196419744244,0.0],[-122.414074529441834,37.807372411773571,0.0],[-122.413922960064369,37.806632537794691,0.0],[-122.415331176192808,37.806450649477362,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0022001","BLKLOT": "0022001","BLOCK_NUM": "0022","LOT_NUM": "001","FROM_ST": "417","TO_ST": "431","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.416114311330062,37.806737451517755,0.0],[-122.41618894941837,37.807113534619511,0.0],[-122.415718983138206,37.807173227021444,0.0],[-122.415644044348952,37.806795612884407,0.0],[-122.416114311330062,37.806737451517755,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0022010","BLKLOT": "0022010","BLOCK_NUM": "0022","LOT_NUM": "010","FROM_ST": "475","TO_ST": "495","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.416971672553444,37.806488377472554,0.0],[-122.41700167222325,37.80649625759645,0.0],[-122.417031495189491,37.806504552438753,0.0],[-122.417127672791466,37.806994296293247,0.0],[-122.41665891491958,37.807053839443512,0.0],[-122.416533599609835,37.806422417965102,0.0],[-122.41656970021981,37.806424543951238,0.0],[-122.416601165930899,37.80642686871478,0.0],[-122.416632575841973,37.8064296278596,0.0],[-122.416663919734944,37.806432821551766,0.0],[-122.416695188503965,37.806436449038124,0.0],[-122.416726373019927,37.806440508664672,0.0],[-122.416757464153648,37.806444998777444,0.0],[-122.416788450575041,37.806449920461866,0.0],[-122.416819325355917,37.80645526932463,0.0],[-122.416850075984158,37.806461044667891,0.0],[-122.416880696759989,37.806467245683294,0.0],[-122.416911175101603,37.806473868970464,0.0],[-122.416941504173849,37.806480913739506,0.0],[-122.416971672553444,37.806488377472554,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0022012","BLKLOT": "0022012","BLOCK_NUM": "0022","LOT_NUM": "012","FROM_ST": "0","TO_ST": "0","STREET": "UNKNOWN","ST_TYPE": null,"ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.416981125334189,37.806248061728859,0.0],[-122.417031495189491,37.806504552438753,0.0],[-122.41700167222325,37.80649625759645,0.0],[-122.416971672553444,37.806488377472554,0.0],[-122.416941504173849,37.806480913739506,0.0],[-122.416911175101603,37.806473868970464,0.0],[-122.416880696759989,37.806467245683294,0.0],[-122.416850075984158,37.806461044667891,0.0],[-122.416819325355917,37.80645526932463,0.0],[-122.416788450575041,37.806449920461866,0.0],[-122.416757464153648,37.806444998777444,0.0],[-122.416726373019927,37.806440508664672,0.0],[-122.416695188503965,37.806436449038124,0.0],[-122.416663919734944,37.806432821551766,0.0],[-122.416632575841973,37.8064296278596,0.0],[-122.416601165930899,37.80642686871478,0.0],[-122.41656970021981,37.806424543951238,0.0],[-122.416533599609835,37.806422417965102,0.0],[-122.416510547376063,37.806306265917648,0.0],[-122.416981125334189,37.806248061728859,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0022014","BLKLOT": "0022014","BLOCK_NUM": "0022","LOT_NUM": "014","FROM_ST": "510","TO_ST": "540","STREET": "NORTH POINT","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "E"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.415947938876556,37.806375848732884,0.0],[-122.415961910658496,37.806446248793044,0.0],[-122.416056272763413,37.806445001460133,0.0],[-122.416114311330062,37.806737451517755,0.0],[-122.415644044348952,37.806795612884407,0.0],[-122.415570016465665,37.806422589080341,0.0],[-122.415947938876556,37.806375848732884,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0022015","BLKLOT": "0022015","BLOCK_NUM": "0022","LOT_NUM": "015","FROM_ST": "451","TO_ST": "455","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.416510547376063,37.806306265917648,0.0],[-122.416533599609835,37.806422417965102,0.0],[-122.41665891491958,37.807053839443512,0.0],[-122.41618894941837,37.807113534619511,0.0],[-122.416114311330062,37.806737451517755,0.0],[-122.416056272763413,37.806445001460133,0.0],[-122.415961910658496,37.806446248793044,0.0],[-122.415947938876556,37.806375848732884,0.0],[-122.416510547376063,37.806306265917648,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0023002","BLKLOT": "0023002","BLOCK_NUM": "0023","LOT_NUM": "002","FROM_ST": "505","TO_ST": "555","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.417281256257567,37.806567792152514,0.0],[-122.41764528088467,37.806665238171831,0.0],[-122.417864160752799,37.806722362091641,0.0],[-122.417825336539309,37.806816328334072,0.0],[-122.417878846389669,37.806832677628556,0.0],[-122.417890083679467,37.806896259225759,0.0],[-122.417359048329601,37.806963914056567,0.0],[-122.417281256257567,37.806567792152514,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0023003","BLKLOT": "0023003","BLOCK_NUM": "0023","LOT_NUM": "003","FROM_ST": "555","TO_ST": "567","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.417864160752799,37.806722362091641,0.0],[-122.418320409917456,37.806841434079793,0.0],[-122.417890083679467,37.806896259225759,0.0],[-122.417878846389669,37.806832677628556,0.0],[-122.417825336539309,37.806816328334072,0.0],[-122.417864160752799,37.806722362091641,0.0]]]}},{"type": "Feature","properties": {"MAPBLKLOT": "0023004","BLKLOT": "0023004","BLOCK_NUM": "0023","LOT_NUM": "004","FROM_ST": "575","TO_ST": "575","STREET": "BEACH","ST_TYPE": "ST","ODD_EVEN": "O"},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-122.417260779295304,37.806463528609761,0.0],[-122.41730371392299,37.806473725374182,0.0],[-122.417374206660796,37.806493625344373,0.0],[-122.417431432337253,37.806513740971653,0.0],[-122.417556935759791,37.806561445537021,0.0],[-122.417609412458503,37.80658450775212,0.0],[-122.417684876751011,37.806610066521166,0.0],[-122.418408092697632,37.806816415907697,0.0],[-122.418444396919355,37.806820608996794,0.0],[-122.418472190518358,37.806822096291938,0.0],[-122.418320409917456,37.806841434079793,0.0],[-122.417864160752799,37.806722362091641,0.0],[-122.41764528088467,37.806665238171831,0.0],[-122.417281256257567,37.806567792152514,0.0],[-122.417260779295304,37.806463528609761,0.0]]]}}]};
}
```